# JXTable custom PainterHighlighter - paint not called

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I try to implement a custom painter highlighter but the paint method of the painter is never called. In the attached example, no special CellRenderer is used. The LAF is Nimbus. What is wrong?

```
public final class HighlighterExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      createUi();
    }
  });
}

private static void createUi() {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setTitle("Example");
  frame.setSize(500, 500);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  try {
    for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
      // Metal
      if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        break;
      }
    }

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  createContent(frame.getContentPane());
  frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static void createContent(final Container parent) {
  JXTable table = new JXTable();
  table.setModel(new ExampleModel());
  table.addHighlighter(new PainterHighlighter() {
    @Override
    protected boolean canHighlight(final Component component, final ComponentAdapter adapter) {
      Boolean value = Boolean.parseBoolean(adapter.getValue(0).toString());
      final boolean canHighlight = value && super.canHighlight(component, adapter);
      System.out.println("can highlight: " + canHighlight);
      return canHighlight;
    }

    @Override
    public Painter getPainter() {
      return new Painter() {
        @Override
        public void paint(final Graphics2D g, final Object object, final int width, final int height) {
          System.out.println("paint");
          g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
          g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        }
      };
    }
  });
  parent.add(new JScrollPane(table));
}

private static class ExampleModel extends AbstractTableModel {

  final static String[][] data = {
      {"true", "Donald", "Duck"},
      {"false", "Dagober", "Duck"}
  };


  @Override
  public int getRowCount() {
    return data.length;
  }

  @Override
  public int getColumnCount() {
    return data[0].length;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getValueAt(final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex) {
    return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
  }
}
}
```

Comment: The LAF is Numbus. What is wrong? == Numbus

Comment: The highlighter framework does not work with the nimbus LAF?

Comment: use without Nimbus L&F, excelent decorations with Substance, note Subtance has own SubstabceXxxXxxRenderer

Comment: highlighting doesn't works without override Painter from Nimbus Plaf, but use Standard XxxRenderer instead of bothering with keys from UIManager (have to override all keys and corredtly, otherwise everything ....)

Comment: Another LAF is not an option, the solution has to work with Nimbus. Is there another way to decorate a row with custom painting code? I.e. is there a simple way to cross an entire row out?

Comment: Another LAF is not an option, the solution has to work with Nimbus. == search for injection (keys for UIManager) from xml file, use Standard Renderers concept (forgot to modify any keys)

Comment: Is there another way to decorate a row with custom painting code? == Standard Renderers concept (simple standards as you can see here, there, evewhere for Metal L&F works for JList/JComboBox/JTree/JTable)